# lxml text_content can not get whole text

Tags: python, lxml, html-content-extraction

As title says, `div[@class="posts-cont"]` contain a lot of sentences, but  `text_content()` seems only get the first sentence splited by `<br>...`

```
>>>import requests
>>>from lxml import html
>>>url = 'http://club.kdnet.net/dispbbs.asp?boardid=1&id=9964430'
>>>r = requests.get(url)
>>>h = html.document_fromstring(r.content)
>>>h.cssselect('.posts-cont')[0].text_content()

   u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\u6587/\u65b0\u6d6a\u8d22\u7ecf\u4e13\u680f\u4f5c\u5bb6\xa0\xa0\u4e01\u9053\u9f50\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\u4ea4\u6d41\u7279\u9ad8\u538b\u8f93\u7535\u5efa\u8bbe\u6210\u672c\u6700\u9ad8\u4e14'
```

the block:

```
                    <div class="posts-cont" style="word-spacing: 2px;">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;文/新浪财经专栏作家&nbsp;&nbsp;丁道齐<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;交流特高压输电建设成本最高且沒有经济实用输电距离，世界各国几十年前就弃用交流特高压远距离输电采用直流远距离输电。采用交流特高压远距离输电及组网比采用特高压直流远距离输电加超高压交流加强受端电网的组网就贵2倍以上。【专栏讨论：特高压到底该不该上】<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img SRC="http://i3.sinaimg.cn/cj/2014/0402/U10971P31DT20140402113618.jpg" alt="" border="0" / onclick="javascript:if((!(this.width<600))||(!(this.width<100)&&!(this.height<100)))window.open('http://club.kdnet.net/atlas/index.asp?id=9964430&pic='+escape(this.src.replace('.cat898.com/','.kdnet.net/').replace('/UploadSmall/','/Upload/')));"  class="img-src"   onload="javascript:if (this.width>=600 || (this.width>=100 && this.height>=100)){this.style.cursor='pointer';}if(this.width>=600){this.height=parseInt(this.height*600/this.width);this.width=600;}">交特高压输电建设成本最高且沒有经济实用输电距离。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;中国500千伏超高压区域电网具有持续发展的广阔空间<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;完全沒有必要再建一个1000千伏交流特高压电网<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;原国家电力监管委员会、国家能源局于2012年10月发布的《“十一五”电网运营情况调研报告》(下称《电网调研报告》) 称，“从国际范围看，电网与中国情况最为接近的非美国莫属。比较说明，中国220千伏及以上电网线路利用率太低，与国外差距太大，浪费严重”。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;230～750千伏线路利用率(2010年)<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;装机容量 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(万千瓦)<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;230～750千伏 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;线路长度(公里)<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;线路利用率 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(千瓦/公里)<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;中/外线路利用率 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;比较<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;线路利用率提升到美、日水平后 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;中国的装机容量(倍/万千瓦)<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;中国<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;96641<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;432110<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2236<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;中/美53.3%<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1.88倍/181315<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;美国<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;113856<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;271598<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4192<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;日本<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;7846<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;中/日28.5%<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.51倍/339091<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;500千伏线路利用率(2010年)<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;接入500千伏系装机容量 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(万千瓦)/ 占全国比例<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;500千伏 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;线路长度(公里)<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;线路利用率 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(千瓦/公里)<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;中/美线路 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;利用率比较<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;利用率提升到美国水平后中国 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;500千伏系统装机容量(倍/万千瓦)<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;中国<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;62297/70%<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;127099<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4905<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;35.5%<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2.82 /1755484<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;美国<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;56928/50%<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;41227<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13808<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;100%<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1.0/56928<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;同直流特高压相比<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;交流特高压输电在经济性、环保性方面是最差的<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(1) 交特高压输电建设成本最高且沒有经济实用的输电距离。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img SRC="http://i2.sinaimg.cn/cj/2014/0402/U10971P31DT20140402111121.jpg" alt="" border="0" / onclick="javascript:if((!(this.width<600))||(!(this.width<100)&&!(this.height<100)))window.open('http://club.kdnet.net/atlas/index.asp?id=9964430&pic='+escape(this.src.replace('.cat898.com/','.kdnet.net/').replace('/UploadSmall/','/Upload/')));"  class="img-src"   onload="javascript:if (this.width>=600 || (this.width>=100 && this.height>=100)){this.style.cursor='pointer';}if(this.width>=600){this.height=parseInt(this.height*600/this.width);this.width=600;}">图1 ±500、±660千伏超高压直流、±800千伏特高压直流和<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;从图1中可以清晰的得出如下规律：<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a、交流输电的单价成本不论电压高低均随着输电距离的增加而增加；反之，直流输电的单价成本不论电压高低均随输电距离的增加而减小。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;远距离、大容量的交流特高压输电工程单位成本约为直流特高压输电工程的3.7～4.7倍。換句话说，远距离、大容量的直流特高压输电系统是一个技术先进、高效率的输电系统，其效率约为远距离、大容量的交流特高压输电系统的3.7～4.7倍。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b、图1中500千超高压交流与±500千伏超高压直流输电的单价成本变化趋势线在大约600公里处相交，该点称为交、直流输电的经济临界输送距离。这标志着输电距离在600公里以内，采用500千伏超高压交流输电比较经济；而超过600公里釆用超高压直流输电比较经济，而且愈远愈经济。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;c、比较图1中交、直流特高压建设单位成本的变化趋势来看，无论输电距离多少，交流特高压的建设成本永远高于特高压直流；在可能的应用输电距离范围内，交流特高压建设成本也远高于±500千伏超高压直流输电；在500千伏超高压交流输电的适用范围(800公里～900公里)内，交流特高压建设成本也远高于500千伏超高压交流输电。这就验证了交流特高压输电在任何条件下都没有经济适用的输电距离，<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;近距离不如500千伏超高压交流，中长距离不如±500千伏或±660千伏超高压直流，长远距离不如±800千伏特高压直流。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;晋東南－南阳－荆门交流特高压试验示范工程验证了1000千伏特高压交流输电系统相对于其他输电系统方案在经济上是最差的，更无市场竞争力。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;正因为如此，世界各国几十年前就弃用交流特高压远距离输电，而普遍采用直流远距离输电。中国南方电网和内蒙电网规划也验证了：采用交流特高压远距离输电及组网方案比采用特高压直流远距离输电加超高压交流加强受端电网的组网方案就贵出2倍以上。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2) 1000千伏交流特高压远距离大容量输电除了建设成本高昂，在其它方面，如线路损耗、占用土地以及环保等方面也无经济性可言。 <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;比较交、直流两种输电功率损失的大小最基本的初始条件是在同一个电压等级水平下进行，这才能得出客观公正的结论。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;在输电功率1200万千瓦、输电距离2000公里的条件下，±800千伏特高压直流输电的功率损失率为1.5%；±1000千伏特高压直流功率损失率为1%。而1000kV交流特高压输电线路的功率损失率为2.3%(投资为±800千伏特高压直流1.36倍，功率损失却是±800千伏特高压直流的1.53倍)。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;由此可知，同样电压等级下的交、直流输电，直流输电的损耗总是比交流低。但是这还不是最终的结论。由于影响输电损耗大小的因素不仅与电压有关，更与导线的截面积大小以及在输送相同有功功率、相同距离的情况下，输电线回路数才是决定交、直流输电功率损失的决定因素，而这些因素最终会反映在输电线建设的总成本上。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;直流与交流输电损失的比较必须紧紧以输电系统的建设成本为前提才能得出客观的结果。在综合比较投资的差异后，实际上电压比较高的交流输电损失比电压低的直流输电还要高。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;图2表示在输电距离为2000km、输电容量为12000MW输电方式下，不同电压等级的AC/DC输电的建设费用与线路功率损耗的关系。显然±800KV的UHVDC输电线路的建设费用或传输损耗都是最低的。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img SRC="http://i1.sinaimg.cn/cj/2014/0402/U10971P31DT20140402111416.jpg" alt="" border="0" / onclick="javascript:if((!(this.width<600))||(!(this.width<100)&&!(this.height<100)))window.open('http://club.kdnet.net/atlas/index.asp?id=9964430&pic='+escape(this.src.replace('.cat898.com/','.kdnet.net/').replace('/UploadSmall/','/Upload/')));"  class="img-src"   onload="javascript:if (this.width>=600 || (this.width>=100 && this.height>=100)){this.style.cursor='pointer';}if(this.width>=600){this.height=parseInt(this.height*600/this.width);this.width=600;}">图2 不同输电方式下输电线的费用相对于线路损耗的函数<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;由图2可知：<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a、在输送同样功率的情况下，要获得相同的功率损失率，1000千伏交流特高压输电的建设成本要比±800千伏直流特高压输电成本高得多。例如要获得3%的损失率，交流特高压输电的建设成本要比±800千伏直流输电成本高达1.33倍；<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b、在输送同样功率的情况下，用同样的投资建成的交流特高压输电系统的功率损失率要比直流特高压输电系统的功率损失大得多。交流特高压输电系统的功率损失率最大的可以为直流特高压的2.0倍。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;因为直流架空输电线只用两根，导线电阻损耗比交流输电小；没有感抗和容抗的无功损耗；没有集肤效应，导线的截面利用充分。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000千伏交流特高压线路的电晕损耗，要比交流超高压输电高得多，超高压输电的电晕损耗一般为其电阻损耗的20%左右，而交流特高压线路因为电压等级高，线路所经过的地区海拔高度和天气情况复杂，有资料显示，在坏天气下单回路特高压线路的电晕损耗高达每公里1600千瓦，而直流架空线路的“空间电荷效应”使其电晕损耗和无线电干扰都比交流输电线路小得多。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2) 交流特高压大容量、远距离送输电，输电线占地面积和消耗钢材(3318, -10.00,-0.30%)要比交流特高压多得多。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1,000kV交流线路的走廊为直流输电线路的2.8～3.3倍，又为同塔双回500kV紧凑型线路的1.7～1.9倍。国家电网[微博]公司强调节省线路走廊是建设全国百万伏联网的主要理由之一，事实证明适得其反，1,000kV线路最浪费土地资源。此外，在输送同样容量的情况下，HVDC铁塔的规模要比HVAC铁塔小得多(参见图3)。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img SRC="http://i0.sinaimg.cn/cj/2014/0402/U10971P31DT20140402111505.jpg" alt="" border="0" / onclick="javascript:if((!(this.width<600))||(!(this.width<100)&&!(this.height<100)))window.open('http://club.kdnet.net/atlas/index.asp?id=9964430&pic='+escape(this.src.replace('.cat898.com/','.kdnet.net/').replace('/UploadSmall/','/Upload/')));"  class="img-src"   onload="javascript:if (this.width>=600 || (this.width>=100 && this.height>=100)){this.style.cursor='pointer';}if(this.width>=600){this.height=parseInt(this.height*600/this.width);this.width=600;}">图3 相同的输电容量，HVAC和HVDC线路铁塔规模的比较。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3) 交流特高压远距离大容量输电的CO2排放当量比直流特高压远距离大容量输电高1.0倍。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;德国学者根据国际标准化组织 (ISO) 对电力传输网络进行生命周期评估 (LCA，Life CycleAssessment) 的14040 ff标准，开展了对在不同配置下，交直流特高压输电系统与420kV交流超高压系统的生命周期评估比较研究，及其对全球暖化潜在的影响。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;由图4可知，±800千伏的特高压输电线的建设导致全球暖化潜在值(以CO2的排放当量吨/年表示)是最低的，而1000千伏交流特高压的CO2的排放当量是±800千伏的特高压输电的1.0倍。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img SRC="http://i2.sinaimg.cn/cj/2014/0402/U10971P31DT20140402111615.jpg" alt="" border="0" / onclick="javascript:if((!(this.width<600))||(!(this.width<100)&&!(this.height<100)))window.open('http://club.kdnet.net/atlas/index.asp?id=9964430&pic='+escape(this.src.replace('.cat898.com/','.kdnet.net/').replace('/UploadSmall/','/Upload/')));"  class="img-src"   onload="javascript:if (this.width>=600 || (this.width>=100 && this.height>=100)){this.style.cursor='pointer';}if(this.width>=600){this.height=parseInt(this.height*600/this.width);this.width=600;}">图4 不同电压等级的AC/DC输电线路由于输电损耗及相应设备的制造引起的CO2排放量。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(3) 同交流输电相比，直流输电不提供短路电流，不需要电抗补偿，降低系统建设成本，适合超长距离送电。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;由此可见，通过对在建设和运行实踐中取得的这些大量数据分析可以看出，在远距输电和电网建设上，交流特高压技术的应用滥用了国家大量资源(涉及国内电力、机械行业的科研、制造、设计、高校等100余家单位近5万人)，不仅技术不可取，经济上也处于劣势，其建设成本要比高压直流输电高出二倍以上，更严重的是交流特高压极大地增加了电网发生连锁性大停电事故的安全风险。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000千伏交流特高压是安全风险最高的<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;寄生在500千伏超高压电网上的不稳定电网架构<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)将1000千伏交流特高压输电能力和输电距离吹捧为500千伏，交流超高压输电的4～5倍是违背电力系统基本原理的胡言乱语。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;在送、受端系统不变的情况下，同一条输电线路在1000千伏运行时的输电容量PlU与500千伏运行时的输电容量PlS之比TCR为：<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img SRC="http://i0.sinaimg.cn/cj/2014/0402/U10971P31DT20140402111815.jpg" alt="" border="0" / onclick="javascript:if((!(this.width<600))||(!(this.width<100)&&!(this.height<100)))window.open('http://club.kdnet.net/atlas/index.asp?id=9964430&pic='+escape(this.src.replace('.cat898.com/','.kdnet.net/').replace('/UploadSmall/','/Upload/')));"  class="img-src"   onload="javascript:if (this.width>=600 || (this.width>=100 && this.height>=100)){this.style.cursor='pointer';}if(this.width>=600){this.height=parseInt(this.height*600/this.width);this.width=600;}">公式一<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;式中k为500千伏线路阻抗与同长度1000千伏线路阻抗之比，通常k=4～5；XCU为1000千伏输电系统综合阻抗；XCS为500千伏输电系统综合阻抗。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;由上式可知，因为输电系统送、受端系统和特高压升降变压器阻抗的存在，1000千伏交流特高压线路的输电容量PlU永远不可能达到500千伏交流超高压线路输电容量PlS的4～5倍。前者对后者的比值TCR完全由两种电压等级输电系统的综合电抗的比值所决定。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;以晋东南－荆门交流特高压试验工程为例，晋东南－荆门交流特高压线路的最大输电能力PlU为230万千瓦。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;如果将晋东南－荆门交流特高压线路降为500千伏电压运行，同样送、受端系统条件下，同样距离的超高压线路最大输电能力PlS为108万千瓦；这就是说，1000千伏特高压的输电容量仅为超高压500千伏运行时的2.13倍，而不是4～5倍。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;同样，在相同导线截面下，1000千伏线路的电气距离(阻抗)虽然相当于500千伏线路1/k(1/5～1/4)，但在输送相同功率的情况下，由于线路两端特高压变压器的电抗的存在，1000千伏电压的输电距离也不是500千伏输电线输电距离的4～5倍。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;在输送相同功率Pl的情况下，500千伏输电距离l500与1000千伏输电距离l1000的关系如下：<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img SRC="http://i1.sinaimg.cn/cj/2014/0402/U10971P31DT20140402111942.jpg" alt="" border="0" / onclick="javascript:if((!(this.width<600))||(!(this.width<100)&&!(this.height<100)))window.open('http://club.kdnet.net/atlas/index.asp?id=9964430&pic='+escape(this.src.replace('.cat898.com/','.kdnet.net/').replace('/UploadSmall/','/Upload/')));"  class="img-src"   onload="javascript:if (this.width>=600 || (this.width>=100 && this.height>=100)){this.style.cursor='pointer';}if(this.width>=600){this.height=parseInt(this.height*600/this.width);this.width=600;}">公式二<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;式中l500、l1000分别为在输送相同功率Pl条件下，500千伏线路输送功率Pl时的允许输电距离和在此功率Pl条件下1000千伏线路输电距离；lt =(Xt1+Xt2)/ X0为1000千伏输电线路两端升、降压变压器短路电抗的等值线路长度(公里)；X0为1000千伏输电线路单位电抗(Ω/公里) ；Xl1000、Xl500分别为1000千伏输电线路和500千伏输电线路的电抗(Ω) 。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;由此可知，只要有特高压变压器的存在，1000千伏允许输送的距离永远达不到500千伏允许输送距离的4～5倍。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;当晋东南～荆门特高压交流试验工程降压至500千伏运行时，在输送相同功率230万千瓦的情况下，允许输送的距离l 500=279公里。特高压输电的距离仅是超高输电距离的2.31倍。主要是因为送、受两端升、降压变压器较大的阻抗，阻抗愈大，交流特高压输送的距离愈短。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;由上可知，因为交流特高压输电线路两端升、降压变压器的存在，1000千伏线路的输电容量永远不可能按电压的平方关系达到500千伏输电能力的4～5倍；在输送相同功率的情况下，1000千伏特高压输电线路的最远送电距离也永远达不到500千伏线路的4～5倍。交流特高压试验示范工程的数据证实，交流特高压输电的能力和输电距离都不会超过500千伏线路的2.5倍。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2) 1000千伏交流特高压输电线路输电容量为500万千瓦的稳定输电距离约为300公里。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;在满足静态稳定裕度20%、线路受端电压降落为5%和线路两端高压并联电抗补偿度为70%的前提下，按照送、受两端500千伏系统最大允许短路电流50千安计算，全线安装40%串联电容补偿，送、受两端都装设两组300万千伏安变压器，可以计算出1000千伏交流特高压输电线路稳定输送500万千瓦的输电距离约为300公里。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;因此，为了远距离输电，必须将长线路分段为300公里左右的短线路实行接力送电，在每一分段点必须得到500千伏系统的电压支持才能保持交流特高压较高的输电能力。而接入交流特高压输电线路各分段点的每个500千伏电网的系统强度通常要求达到短路电流30～50千安水平(电网等效容量约2600～4330万千瓦)。这种能力一般在大都市负荷中心才具有。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;如果不能达到这些要求，交流特高压输电正常运行的设计功率就可能落入不安全稳定的区域，电压稳定性也可能受到威胁，示范工程的设计功率不能运行就是案例。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;这些都证明了交流特高压远距输电和交流特高压电网是效力十分低下的电网技术。交流特高压分段落点输电的要求不仅威胁电网安全，而且也严重地降低了交流特高压输电的经济性。这也正是交流特高压远距离输电建设成本居高不下的主要原因之一。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;国网公司为了掩饰交流特高压输电必须“分段落点”的这一固有弱点，偏偏将其美化为交流特高压可以“灵活落点，而直流输电却不能”。问题的要害在于，如果沒有“灵活落点”，交流特高压就不能实现远距离、大容量、低效率输电。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;比较直流输电方式则没有这种安全限制：交流特高压示范工程输电距离仅645公里，设计功率280万千瓦不能运行，平时只能维持200万千瓦运行，而向家坝至上海±800千伏直流输电距离近2000公里，为示范工程的3.1倍；输电功率高达700万千瓦已经运行成功，为示范工程的3.5倍，两者相比昭然若揭。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(3) 交流特高压输电的特性决定了交流特高压电网必须永远依赖于1000/500千伏电磁环网的存在，它破坏了500千伏超高压电网的安全性，扩散了电网的脆弱性，成为寄生在500千伏超高压电网上的怪胎。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1) 特高压交流线路产生的巨大充电无功功率随着线路潮流的变化引起1000/500千伏网架电压的飘移浮动，将增加电压稳定性破坏的风险。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2) 为保证交流特高压稳定的输电能力，必须在300公里左右就要有500千伏网络的支撑，为此构成的1000/500千伏电磁环网，实际上是上弱(1000千伏网络)下强(500千伏网络)，而该电磁环网自投运之日始就基本不能解开，1000千伏系统必须寄生在500千伏超高压系统上才能存活(参见图5)。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img SRC="http://i3.sinaimg.cn/cj/2014/0402/U10971P31DT20140402112125.jpg" alt="" border="0" / onclick="javascript:if((!(this.width<600))||(!(this.width<100)&&!(this.height<100)))window.open('http://club.kdnet.net/atlas/index.asp?id=9964430&pic='+escape(this.src.replace('.cat898.com/','.kdnet.net/').replace('/UploadSmall/','/Upload/')));"  class="img-src"   onload="javascript:if (this.width>=600 || (this.width>=100 && this.height>=100)){this.style.cursor='pointer';}if(this.width>=600){this.height=parseInt(this.height*600/this.width);this.width=600;}">&nbsp;&nbsp;图5 1000交流特高压输电必须取得500千伏超高压电网的支撑，形成多重1000/500千伏电磁环网，破坏了分区分层的电网结构。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;高低压电磁环网的存在将使输电线路的暂态稳定极限大幅度降低。正因为如此，已建、在建的三条交流特高压输电线的输电功率只能按设计值的一半运行，极大地降低了原本效率就不高的交流特高压输电线的使用率。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(4) 交流特高压及三华交流特高压电网引发连锁性大停电事故的概率将十余倍地增大。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img SRC="http://i0.sinaimg.cn/cj/2014/0402/U10971P31DT20140402112203.jpg" alt="" border="0" / onclick="javascript:if((!(this.width<600))||(!(this.width<100)&&!(this.height<100)))window.open('http://club.kdnet.net/atlas/index.asp?id=9964430&pic='+escape(this.src.replace('.cat898.com/','.kdnet.net/').replace('/UploadSmall/','/Upload/')));"  class="img-src"   onload="javascript:if (this.width>=600 || (this.width>=100 && this.height>=100)){this.style.cursor='pointer';}if(this.width>=600){this.height=parseInt(this.height*600/this.width);this.width=600;}">&nbsp;&nbsp;图6 “三华”UHV同步电网与华东／华中／华北三大区域电网发生超过800万千瓦及以上停电损失k的概率p(k)比较。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;在图6中左边蓝色曲线表示现行中国“三华”电网中每个区域电网的幂律特性(负幂指数-γ =1.401)，形成“三华”交流特高压电网后的幂律特性接近于美国东部电网的特性(右侧黑色曲线，负幂指数-γ =1. 0)。这样在发生同样损失800万千瓦规模以上的大停电事故的情况下，“三华”特高压同步电网发生事故的概率为现在分区运行情况下发生事故概率的15倍。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;从图6中，还可以看出，正是由于中国原有500千伏区域超高压电网规模不大、结构清晰、复杂性程度不高(负幂律指数大) ，发生800万千瓦以上规模损失的大停电事故的概率几乎为零(约0.2%)。因此，安全可靠的分区分层的清晰电网结构和适度的超高压同步电网规模才是中国至今未发生全国或全大区范围的大停电事故的根本原因。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;正在积极推行中的“三华”特高压联网，以及特高压交流联网带来难以解决的电磁环网问题，实质上都会将中国原来安全可靠的直流(个别弱交流联网)联网的分区分层结构变成一个分区不清、难以分层、电力通过电网对电网传送，负荷任意转移的不安全、不经济、不环保的庞大的、更加复杂的交流同步电网结构，这样的电网结构危害深远。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;同步电网间的<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;异步互联是世界现代大电网发展的主流趋势<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;从世界范围看，世界上不断发生的大停电事故给社会经济和人类生活带来的严重后果，以及世界性的能源危机的逼近和人类对能源需求的不断增长，人们对新能源的广泛开发和安全利用寄以巨大的希望。电网间实施同步互联的发展趋势已经受到安全、经济和环保等条件的制约。同步电网不是电压愈高、容量愈大愈安全，必须控制同步电网规模。这样才能有效地控制系统的复杂性和脆弱性的扩散。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;图7表示按年度顺序美加电网、欧洲电网、其它国家电网发生重大停电事故次数所占各相应电网总事故次数的百分比(%)变化趋势。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img SRC="http://i2.sinaimg.cn/cj/2014/0402/U10971P31DT20140402112344.jpg" alt="" border="0" / onclick="javascript:if((!(this.width<600))||(!(this.width<100)&&!(this.height<100)))window.open('http://club.kdnet.net/atlas/index.asp?id=9964430&pic='+escape(this.src.replace('.cat898.com/','.kdnet.net/').replace('/UploadSmall/','/Upload/')));"  class="img-src"   onload="javascript:if (this.width>=600 || (this.width>=100 && this.height>=100)){this.style.cursor='pointer';}if(this.width>=600){this.height=parseInt(this.height*600/this.width);this.width=600;}">图7 世界各国(地区)电网发生事故次数占各自电网总事故的百分比(%)变化趋势图。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;世界电网大停电事故的发生日渐增加，其直接的原因可能是灾害性天气或人为失误，但事故的扩大基本上是电力系统规模不断扩张导致的复杂性和脆弱性所致。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;电网随着复杂性的增加而导致的系统脆弱性同时迅速扩散，在包括灾害天气或一个看起来“微不足道”的干扰下，所有积累的脆弱性，如电网结构不合理，维修欠佳和不确定性的干扰和/或近临界状态的缓慢变化都可能被“激活”，从而导致更加严重甚至连锁性事故的发生。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(1) 为将事故危害尽量控制在有限范围内，限制同步电网规模，发展同步电网间异步互联，已成为世界大电网发展的主流趋势。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;现代电网技术的进步是一把双刃剑。它给电网带来巨大的经济和社会效益的同时，随着互联电网的不断扩大，其严重后果亦日渐显现：<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1)互联电网内各子电网EPS/ICS/MCS间相互依赖性日趋严重，电力系统及其关联的控制和通信系统的任何一个脆弱部位都会遭到人为或自然的攻击，而导致电力系统灾难性事故的发生；<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2)随电力市场发展，网间潮流交换频度及数量将急剧增加，迫使电网经常运行在趋于极限的临界态；<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3)信息交换及信息量大幅增加，自动化系统及其管理更为复杂，事故风险增大。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2) 限制同步电网规模、降低电网复杂性、发展同步电网间异步互联更有利于能源资源优化配置和新能源的广泛开发和安全利用，是当今世界在安全、经济和环保等条件制约下各国发展大电网的最佳选择，更是提高电网安全性和生存性，建设坚强国家电网的重大战略举措。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;在《特高压交直流电网》一书中称“世界范围内的跨国、跨区互联电网呈现蓬勃发展趋势，联网范围不断扩大”。特别以美国和欧盟的“Grid 2030”和“Super grid”为例加以说明。但在说明中只字不提他们为限制同步电网的扩大，而釆用直流输电技术实现跨国、跨区互联的事实；只字不提欧洲以异步互联方式将已有的各国交流电网融合形成超级电网，实现将目前松散联系的欧洲电力市场构建为欧洲统一电力市场，而借“欧洲统一电力市场”之名推销“必须建设交流特高压电网才能形成中国统一电力市场” 的私货。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1)美国电力改革的纲领性文件——《电网2030－电力下一个100年国家愿景》(GRID 2030)明确提出，以大容量高压直流输电线路及高温超导输电系统建立跨接美国东西海岸骨干环形网及其联接支路的宏伟计划，从而解决美国百年来形成的复杂交流自由联网结构无法解决的根本问题。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;为了降低电网的复杂性，提高电网的安全性，美国电力科学研究院EPRI和直流互联公司DC Interconnect Co。研究了美欧多次重大停电的教训，建议实施改造旧电网的“綠色计划”，采用“电网分割技术”，将美国规模巨大的东部同步电网(7.55亿千瓦)用直流分隔为4个交流区，西部同步电网(2亿千瓦) 用直流分隔为2个交流区。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2) 日本学者对日本的关西、中国、九州、四国的串行电力系统进行的研究表明，若通过在关西与中国、中国与九州、九州与四国、四国与关西间采用直流方式连接，将可大大抑制短路电流，并实现小系统向大系统的输电，还可以极大地提高电网运行的安全性和可靠性。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3)作为欧盟FP6框架计划的一部分，由欧盟提出了以HVDC技术连接各国已有的交流电网，建设一个可使可再生能源电力远距离传输的大规模的“超级电网”(super grid，SG) 和超级智能电网(super smart Grid，SSG)的构想。以实现<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;充分利用非洲北部沙漠地区丰富的太阳能和风能资源，满足地中海地区和欧洲大陆的电力需求SSG实际上是分布式和小型设施构成的去中央化的可再生电力为主的区域性智能电网与超级电网相结合的产物。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;超级智能电网SSG的基本架构是新建密集的HVDC线路，以异步互联方式将已有的各国交流电网融合形成超级电网，实现将目前松散联系的欧洲电力市场构建为欧洲统一电力市场，进而实现北非国家与欧洲电网的互联，使电力系统更加可靠、电价更为低廉。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;在面临核电站将要关闭，进一步扩大风能、太阳能及再生能源的开发和传输范围的情况下，德国运营商在2014年年初公布了一系列相配套的以±400千伏高压直流为主的输电工程，例如为解决北部风电向南部负荷中心送电的、长800公里的“南部链接”工程，德国运营商明确宣布，他们不采用1000 千伏特高压交流输电技术，而釆用超高压直流，因为特高压输电资本要求太高。运营商们正在考虑将一些现有的交流输电线路改造为直流输电，以提高他们的输电能力。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4)中国南方电网也将控制同步电网规模作为提高电网安全性和生存性的重要战略措施。到2020年，现有的南网五省(区)同步电网将逐步形成规模适中、结构清晰、相对独立的2个同步电网。其中以云南省电网为主体形成送端同步电网，其余4省(区)电网形成一个同步电网。《规划》中，南方电网将主要采用直流输电技术实现跨区域送电。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5) 2005年9月美国IEEE大会中，俄国科学院 L.S.Belyaev, 在《东亚电力基础设施的前景》(Prospectsof Electricity Infrastructure in East Asia)论文中，提出一个为节省能源的亚洲联网方案，联网区域包括俄、蒙、中、日、南韩、北朝鲜，联络线输电距离为470～3500km，全部用±500kV或±600kV直流输电联网，再也不提前苏联时期的交流特高压了。这充分说明将来世界电网的发展是直流输电愈来愈广泛了，特别用於远距离输电和交流电网间互联，根本不需要交流特高压了。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;6) 构建分布式和小型设施构成的去中央化的可再生电力(太阳能、风能等新能源和可再生能源)为主的区域性智能电网和微电网是保障社会基本用电、解决偏远地区和居民分散区用电以及应对自然灾害和战争环境下保持电网的生存性的最佳方案。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;建设采用新能源供电的小型微电网，能够解决偏远地区和居民分散区的用电问题。在印度，约有40%的人口生活在电网触及不到的地方。印度能源部门称，作为一项长期解决方案，微电网是印度崭新能源革命的重要组成部分。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;在印度，目前几乎所有的小型微电网都是由太阳能供电的，但也有20到30个微型电网是由水电站和生物质电站供电的。据保守估计，迄今为止，小型微电网至少为印度12.5万户家庭提供了电力。<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2003年“8.14”北美大停电事故让美国东部大面积陷入一片黑暗之中，但一个一个装备有分布式能源系统的企业、学校、医院和政府机构却在“大停电”中一片灯火辉煌，显示了电网应有的顽强的生存性。而国网公司实施的以交流特高压远距离大容量输电为核心的“一特四大”战略在自然灾害和战争环境下都是无能为力的，更不能解决偏远地区和居民分散区的用电问题。<br><br>
                </div>
```

Comment: Taking the first text node instead of all is definitely a bug: http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html says "text_content():Returns the text content of the element, including the text content of its children, with no markup."

Answer (score 0):

It does look like this might just be a bug in lxml. Perhaps try using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)? It is great at handling wonky html files.